# Calculating distances between 3-D coordinates in large data set...with a minor twist

Tags: excel

I am trying to use excel to calculate the distance between two points with x,y and z coordinates using the formula distance=SQRT((X1-X2)^2+(Y1-Y2)^2+(Z1-Z2)^2)). The formula works just fine for single calculations my problem lies in my ability to apply this formula to a large table similar to the attached image. (The diagonal should equal zero)

Example of the table I have and the table I want to make:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in excel? Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks, Derrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I am going to do two things -- (1) Outline the solution and (2) Teach you to fish by explaining how to do this in the future.

Okay as some have shown VLOOKUP is your friend however when using this it is best to have your lookup chart on its own page so that you can easily expand it later however if you want to show both on the results page you have examples of doing that as well.

Also keep in mind that programs love numbers -- so whenever you can replace strings with intelligible numbers do so it speeds up processing.

So in my example I put your City Chart on its own sheet (CityChart) as follows

```
City | X | Y | Z
 1     1   1   1
 2     3   4   6
 3     6   7   3
 4     3   5   6
 6    10   5  20
```

So the first thing you want to do is make sure you can retrieve the data from your lookup chart in a manner that you expect.  So on a separate sheet we create a Distance chart as follows:

```
City | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | etc ...
  1
  2
  3
  4
  6
 etc...
```

Then in position 1,1 we do the basic lookup in order to get X1

X1 =>  =VLOOKUP($A2, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)

```
$A2  Means grab the column City number

'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6  Means use the lookup chart on sheet (CityChart) 
                       with this range.  As stated this makes it easier
                       to expand later on.

2   Means in the CityChart get the value from column 2 -- and if you look
    that is our column labeled X

$   Means freeze the following value when copying
```

Press  and the value it shows should be : 1

Now you can copy that cell from 1,1 and paste it to 2,1 through 6,1 and you should get the corresponding results from your CityChart

Now copy the formula without the = sign into a cell for later reference

```
VLOOKUP($A2, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)
```

We conquered hurdle one.

Now we need to get X2

Basically the same formula but instead of grabbing Column 1 we grab Row 1 as follows -- again in cell 1,1 we write

```
X2 =>  =VLOOKUP(B$1, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)
```

Validate that it works, copy it in to cells 1,2 through 1,6 to make sure it returns the appropriate values then copy the formula for later reference

We now have ....

```
X1 =>  =VLOOKUP($A2, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)
X2 =>  =VLOOKUP(B$1, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)
```

So we need to extrapolate this to Y and Z or CityChart Columns 3 and 4 as follows:

```
X1 =>  VLOOKUP($A2, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)
X2 =>  VLOOKUP(B$1, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 2)
Y1 =>  VLOOKUP($A2, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 3)
Y2 =>  VLOOKUP(B$1, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 3)
Z1 =>  VLOOKUP($A2, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 4)
Z2 =>  VLOOKUP(B$1, 'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6, 4)
```

Now we need to expand this and move towards your formula.  We start with setting down our two encapsulating ( ) and then copy/paste our references in adding the subtraction sign as we go

```
(X1 - X2) =>  (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,2) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,2))
(Y1 - Y2) =>  (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,3) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,3))
(Z1 - Z2) =>  (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,4) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,4))
```

Why do this systematically well for one to avoid the mistake that is in your formula for instances -- if you look closely you will see you have one too many ")"

Next we add the ^2 to the end

```
(X1 - X2) =>  (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,2) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,2))^2
(Y1 - Y2) =>  (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,3) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,3))^2
(Z1 - Z2) =>  (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,4) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,4))^2
```

Then all that is left is to put that into your SQRT( ) function along with the + signs

```
SQRT( (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,2) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,2))^2 + (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,3) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,3))^2 + (VLOOKUP($A2,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,4) - VLOOKUP(B$1,'CityChart'!$A$2:$D$6,4))^2 )
```

Once you have the full formula copy it and place it in front of an = sign within cell 1,1 and press return you should get 0

Then copy it and paste it either to the full row or full column -- then copy the full row/column and highlight the remaining cells and paste -- viola fast and easy expansion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula should work.

```
=SQRT((VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($A11,1)),$A$2:$D$6,2,FALSE)-
     (VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(B$10,1)),$A$2:$D$6,2,FALSE)))^2+
(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($A11,1)),$A$2:$D$6,3,FALSE)-
     (VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(B$10,1)),$A$2:$D$6,3,FALSE)))^2+
(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($A11,1)),$A$2:$D$6,4,FALSE)-
     (VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(B$10,1)),$A$2:$D$6,4,FALSE)))^2)
```

1. The RIGHT part of each function takes the "City #" and and retrieves the identifying #
2. The NUMBERVALUE makes the identifying city # a numbervalue rather than text.
3. The first VLOOKUP of each pair uses the column list (presumably Col A) to find the numbers for the first city (make sure the column reference is absolute with the $ in front of the column letter).
4. The second VLOOKUP of each pair uses the row list across the top of the matrix to reference the second cities coordinates (make sure the row reference is absolute with the $ in front of the row number).
5. Use the "$A$2:$D$6" part of the formula to create an absolute reference of the cities' reference numbers and the x,y,z columns of information. (use $ in front of both row numbers and column letters)
6. The third element of each VLOOKUP refers to the column number of the absolute reference (see step 5). In this case x=2, y=3 and z=4.
7. The "false" in each VLOOKUP statement is probabally not necessary, but I like to use it to prevent mistakes. It ensures an 'exact match' in the VLOOKUP formula.

Answer (score 0):

Just to do your homework:

If your sheet looks like this:
[image]

then simply use the arrayformula

```
{=SUM((INDEX($B$2:$D$7,MATCH($A11,$A$2:$A$7,0),)-INDEX($B$2:$D$7,MATCH(B$10,$A$2:$A$7,0),))^2)^0.5}
```

and fill down/right ;)

**EDIT**

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($B$2:$D$7,MATCH($A11,$A$2:$A$7,0),)-INDEX($B$2:$D$7,MATCH(B$10,$A$2:$A$7,0),))^2)^0.5
```

will also work (non-array-formula)